# Flutter always show a popup " appname World like to paste from safari" when paste textfield

Tags: flutter, dart, permissions, textfield, ios16

anyone can help me
I got a new issue when update ios 16 on my device

I create a flutter project and add simple text filed to new application
and build to my iphone 13 that use ios 16

when i try copy some text from another app or safari , once i try to paste to my textfield , always show the popup permission asking would to paste from "app name"

case if you allow 1 time it copy clipboard will can paste without popup but when
you copy new text,and try to paste it show ask permission again

and i try create native project via xcode but the issue not occur on native application
I need to know this is bug right? or some feature from flutter
why ios native project not occur ?

Question:
Can someone tell me about this scenario from flutter project, who can fix it , apple or flutter team?
I need to disable it
How to disable popup or ask only one time or something like
I need to know this bug on flutter project only right?
I need to know why ios native not found issue like this

[image]

I need to disable the popup that show on flutter project
why ios native project not occur

**#### new update ###**
I known about for ios 16.1 will have workaround solution for solved that add permission in general but a setting default to ASK
when user go to set Allow in this it will solved
but why allow in application don't auto change in this permission

question

1. can I force in my code to Allow in the permission?
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cknmm.png)

Comment: I think that's from iOS 16 https://9to5mac.com/2022/06/06/ios-16-permission-copy-paste-between-apps/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What was your work around? I'm having this same issue